# How to generate graphql statements from aws schema.graphql using amplify

Tags: aws-appsync, aws-amplify

So I created `schema.graphql` using `amplify add api` command, but I said No when it offered me to generate queries, mutations and subscriptions.

Now I am wondering, how can I generate them after the fact? Or do I have to go through whole `amplify add api` process again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an additional command that you can use to initiate the code generation.

You can run `amplify configure codegen` to configure it (accepting the defaults is probably fine).  Anytime after you have made schema changes, you can then run `amplify codegen types` to re-generate your types (make sure to run an `amplify push` before you do so).

More info here: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/codegen